# How to optimize a parameter in simulink using genetic algorithm (GA)?

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulink, genetic-algorithm, errorcontrolsystem

I have a simulink model of a control system where a output is being constantly compared with the setpoint and error is being set to the controller. I use a matlab file to call this model and send disturbance. I want to optimize a parameter that affects the value of the controller gains on the basis of the error (i.e., to reduce error). How to use GA to call this simulink file and set parameter at each iteration.

I took help from this link: "https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/343672-how-could-i-connect-simulink-model-to-the-genetic-algorithm-toolbox"

but it is showing error:
"Exiting due to infeasibility: 1 lower range(s) exceeds the corresponding upper range."

Comment: Well, read the error, your specified lower range (`lb`) for the parameters exceeds the upper range (`ub`). Make sure that all values in `ub > lb`.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, but in your case, the error that appears is referred to problems of value of the design variables that exceed the upper/lower boundary level defined in the genetic algorithm.